# Import a txt file without consistent pattern in r

Tags: r

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
'111001', '1', 'C:\Users\dicelab\Desktop\mar\ExPart1_C1.exp', 'default.mlp', '10/3/2017', '12:14:03'
Don't drop out of school.
'121002', '1', 'C:\Users\dicelab\Desktop\mar\ExPart1_C1.exp', 'default.mlp', '10/3/2017', '14:04:13'
he should finish his degree!
```

In the file, one entry was split into two lines. For example, the first entry should look like:

```
'111001', '1', 'C:\Users\dicelab\Desktop\mar\ExPart1_C1.exp', 'default.mlp', '10/3/2017', '12:14:03', 'Don't drop out of school.'
```

Then I want to import the file into R, and each quoted content should be one cell. For example, the first row should look like:

```
 111001 1 C:\Users\dicelab\Desktop\mar\ExPart1_C1.exp default.mlp 10/3/2017 12:14:03 Don't drop out of school
```

In the above example, 111001, 1, C:\Users\dicelab\Desktop\mar\ExPart1_C1.exp and so on are separated and each takes one column.

Comment: So every record is exactly two rows of data? There are no embedded newlines in any of the text lines?

Comment: @MrFlick That's correct!

Answer (score 2):

If each line takes up exactly two row, then you can just split up the file into the csv parts, and the non csv parts. For example

```
lines <- readLines("2row.txt")
dd <- read.csv(text=lines[seq(1, length(lines), by=2)], header=F)
dd$comments = lines[seq(2, length(lines), by=2)]
```

Here we group the odd numbered lines and send those to `read.csv`, then we just paste on the even lines as a column.